# udev rules is not working

Tags: linux, arch-linux, udev

I want to set the key repeat rate using `xset r rate 150 90` when the keyboard is plugged in but the very basic rule I created is not working.

**/etc/udev/rules.d/10-keyboard.rules**

```
ACTION=="add", RUN+="echo hello > /home/s1n7ax/hello"
```

After the rule is added I reloaded the rules `sudo udevadm control --reload`. When the keyboard is unplugged and re-plugged in, rule is not fired (a new firefox instance is not created). Manually triggering the rules is also doesn't fire the rule `sudo udevadm trigger`.

Permissions are as follows for the rule.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39 May  4 19:30 10-keyboard.rules
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: I don't think this is going to work - first, udevd does not DISPLAY variable set, and second it kills long running processes after a timeout.

Comment: I changed it to `RUN+="echo test > /home/s1n7ax/hhhhhhhhh"`. Still doesn't work though

Comment: echo requires a full path... then there's the redirection which won't work... it's not a shell. it's udev. Check doc in `man udev`.